# Error creating bean defined in ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, tomcat, applicationcontext

I am  porting  Spring( v.4.3.2) application from Tomcat7 to Tomcat9. I am running Tomcat as a service on Windows box. in my ApplicationContext.xml I have several Beans profiles defined and I also have bean definitions outside of profiles :

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="utilsDS" />
</bean>
```

.............

....

```
    <bean id="utilsDS" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    </bean>
```

....

```
</beans>
```

When I am starting Tomcat I am passing a JVM option :

-Dspring.profiles.active='UAT'

Tomcat 7 starts my application perfectly fine and I am able to run it. However with Tomcat 9 I am getting an error

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'utilsDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No bean named 'utilsDS' is defined

"applicationContext.xml" are identical on Tomcat 7 and 9 since I used the same WAR to deploy an application. I am not sure what I'm missing.
It seems to me it's something in configuration of Tomcat9 that would resolve the reference. I am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I added context-param to an application "web.xml" and it works :

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
 <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

still not sure why passing JVM option :

-Dspring.profiles.active=dev

didn't work